# Track MKAnnotation drag as it moves?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Is it possible to track coordinate changes to an MKAnnotation *as it moves* during a drag? I've followed the recipe of of managing the view's `dragState`, but if I put some prints in, it seems that the `dragging` state (in `mapView(mapView, view, newState, oldState)`) only happens once at the beginning of the drag. And then when I release, I get the `ending`. But no real time update as it moves.

I could launch a timer that "polls" the annotation during the drag, but I was hoping for something a little less hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be late to the party. I had the same need arise and encountered your post. Here is what I did.

First my map view delegate's view for annotation method. The annotation view is made draggable and a gesture recognizer is added. (My DetailAnnotationView is a subclass of MKAnnotationView. What it brings to the party is not pertinent to our focus.)

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        var annotationView = overviewMap.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: DetailAnnotationView.reuseIdentifier) as? DetailAnnotationView
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = DetailAnnotationView(annotation: nil)
            annotationView!.isDraggable = true
            let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressGestureHandler))
            recognizer.allowableMovement = CGFloat.infinity
            recognizer.delegate = self
            annotationView!.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        }
        annotationView!.updateBounds(self)
        return annotationView
    }
```

Next the gesture handler. The detailAnnotation is an MKPointAnnotation. Note that I am using the result of MKMapView.convert to reposition a map. You can, of course, use it as you wish.

```
@objc func longPressGestureHandler(_ recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .changed:
        guard let annotationView = overviewMap.view(for: detailAnnotation) else { fatalError("Cannot get detail annotation's view") }
        detailMap.region.center = overviewMap.convert(recognizer.location(in: annotationView), toCoordinateFrom: annotationView)
    default: break
    }
}
```

Finally, I allow my gesture recognizer to operate simultaneously with the gesture recognizer that MapKit is using to drag the annotation view.

```
extension DualMapsManager : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return gestureRecognizer is UILongPressGestureRecognizer && gestureRecognizer.delegate === self && otherGestureRecognizer is UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    }
}
```

And there you have it. If you ended up polling then you now have an alternative. If you arrived at a different solution then why not post it?

Answer (score 0):

I *did* end up doing a polling mechanism work. Three methods

```
// helper method to trigger a redraw of the renderer associated with a given overlay
// despite the documentations claim to otherwise, it seems that the parameterized
// version of setNeedsDisplay does a better job of updating caches
func redrawOverlay(_ overlay:RegionOverlay?) {
    guard let overlay = overlay, let renderer = self.mapView.renderer(for: overlay) else { return }
    renderer.setNeedsDisplay(self.mapView.visibleMapRect)
}

// the "worker" method that is called once we enter .dragging state and then
// repeatedly calls myself as long as that .dragging state stays in effect
func updateMapWhileDragging(_ annotationView:MKAnnotationView, first:Bool = false) {
    if annotationView.dragState == .dragging {
        let point = annotationView.bounds.midMid
        let coordinate = self.mapView.convert(point, toCoordinateFrom: annotationView)
        if let annotation = annotationView.annotation as? RegionEditingAnnotation {
            if first {
                annotation.beginMove(at: coordinate)
            }
            else {
                annotation.move(to: coordinate)
            }
            if let overlay = self.findOverlay(region: annotation.region) {
                overlay.region = annotation.region
                self.redrawOverlay(overlay)
            }
        }
        // ding with this method again in 40ms
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(40)) {
            self.updateMapWhileDragging(annotationView)
        }
    }
}

// the MK delegate method where we can handle most of the states with
// boilerplate responses
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationView.DragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationView.DragState) {
    self.shouldZoom = false
    switch newState {
    case .starting:
        view.setDragState(.dragging, animated: true)
    case .dragging:
        self.updateMapWhileDragging(view, first: true)
    case .ending:
        if let annotation = view.annotation as? RegionEditingAnnotation, let mappable = self.selectedOverlay?.mappable {
            annotation.endMoves(at: annotation.coordinate)
            self.selectedOverlay?.region = annotation.region
            self.redrawOverlay(self.selectedOverlay)
            mappable.regionPush(annotation.region)
            view.setDragState(.none, animated: true)
            // call the didSet function directly, because the compiler's too "smart" to reset the same value
            self.selectedOverlay_didSet(from: self.selectedOverlay)
        }
    case .canceling:
        view.setDragState(.none, animated: true)
    case .none:
        break
    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}
```

Here's what it ended up looking like.

[image]

When/if I come back to this, I'll give @Verticon's answer a try.